# django int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Liquor'

Tags: django

In the code bellow, I'm getting the error int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Liquor', but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the value into the

```
storeID = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id)
storeliquor = StoreLiquor.objects.get(SPI=SPI_param)
liquor_param = storeliquor.liquorID
liquor = Liquor.objects.get(id=liquor_param)
```

Comment: Please show your models on a question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `liquor_param` is `Liquor` object.

Replace the last line:

```
liquor = Liquor.objects.get(id=liquor_param)
```

with:

```
liquor = Liquor.objects.get(id=liquor_param.pk) # or liquor_param.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `liquor = Liquor.objects.get(id=liquor_param)` is redundant and not needed in your case.

`liquor_param` or `storeliquor.liquorID` is the `Liquor` object you want to get, to retrieving it from DB again is not efficient.

Comment: That is a far better answer.